# determine whether ByteArrayOutputStream is of type JSONArray or JSONObject?

Tags: java, json, inputstream, bytearrayoutputstream

```
ByteArrayOutputStream result = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
while ((length = inputStream.read(buffer)) != -1) {
        result.write(buffer, 0, length);
}
```

Is there a way to determine whether result contains a JSONObject or a JSONArray? I've been blindly casting it to a JSONObject however, i've hit a case where it is a JSONArray - any help would be appreciated.

JSON API: Using faster jackson and org.json

Thanks in advance

Comment: what JSON API are you using?

Comment: faster jackson and org.json are the two that i can see

Comment: @BigBug can you just look at the first character and see whether it's a `[` or `{`?

Comment: @BigBug or even easier, just have a `try` block where you try to make a JSONObject and then a JSONArray if that throws an exception.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### JSR 353 reference implementation

See https://jsonp.java.net/

These are the Maven dependencies:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.json</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.json-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.json</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.4</version>
    <scope>runtime</scope>
</dependency>
```

And the code sample:

```java
// the JSON classes have package javax.json

ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

// read JSON into baos

ByteArrayInputStream bais = new ByteArrayInputStream(baos.toByteArray());
InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(bais, Charset.forName("UTF-8"));
JsonReader jr = Json.createReader(isr);

JsonStructure js = jr.read();

switch (js.getValueType()) {
    case ARRAY:
        break;
    case OBJECT:
        break;
    case STRING:
        break;
    case NUMBER:
        break;
    case TRUE:
        break;
    case FALSE:
        break;
    case NULL:
        break;
}
```

### FasterXML Jackson

(just a sample that works, most probably not the "best")

Maven dependency:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
    <version>2.6.3</version>
</dependency>
```

Code sample:

```java
// see JsonNodeType
new ObjectMapper().reader().readTree("[]").getNodeType();
```